# Is $f_n=x^n$ weakly convergent in $(\mathscr C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

This is part of an old preliminary exam in Analysis I am working through. For earlier parts of the problem I have already shown that $f_n$ does not converge in $(\mathscr C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$, but does converge in $(\mathscr C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_2)$.

I have an idea of a solution, but I am not at all confident about it and would appreciate other solutions or feedback on mine. Mine is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own earlier answer failed for reasons pointed out by carmichael561. I suspect zhw's answer is correct, but it uses resources more advanced than the classes I've taken (I've had no complex analysis). Since it should be possible to answer my question using the resources of the real analysis classes I've taken, I have worked out a proof that I think succeeds.

We have that for any dual space $(X,\lVert \cdot \rVert)$ and $\{x_n\}\subseteq X$ that $x_n\xrightarrow{w}x$ iff:

1. $\exists c>0$ s.t. $\lVert x_n\rVert\leq c\ \forall n$
2. $\exists M\subseteq X^*$ with $\overline{\mathrm{span}}M=X^*$ s.t. $\forall l\in M$, $l(x_n)\to l(x)$

where $X^*$ is the dual space of $X$.

When $(X,\lVert\cdot\rVert)=(\mathcal C[a,b],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$, it can be shown that $M=\{\delta_t: t\in[a,b]\}$, where $\delta_t\in\mathcal C[a,b]^*$ with $\delta_t(f)=f(t)$, is such that $\overline{\mathrm{span}}M=\mathcal C[a,b]^*$.

Thus $f_n\xrightarrow{w} f$ iff:

1. $\exists c>0$ such that $\lVert f_n\rVert_\infty \leq c\ \forall n$
2. $f_n(t)\to f(t)\ \forall t\in[a,b]$.

Condition (2) above suffices to show that $\{f_n\}$ in this case is not weakly convergent, since $f_n$ converges pointwise to the (noncontinuous) indicator function $f=\mathbf1_{\{x=1\}}$.

Comment: Incidentally, I'd appreciate guidance about MSE norms surrounding accepting answers. I highly suspect zhw's answer is correct, but I haven't accepted it because I don't understand it, and hence (by no fault of zhw) the answer was not very helpful to me. My proof has resolved my confusion, so I accepted it. But it seems unseemly to post multiple answers to my own question and accept one of them, when someone else has posted a (probably) perfectly good answer. I would refrain from accepting any answer, but that would leave my question marked as unanswered, which I understand is not desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be the space of complex Borel measures on $[0,1].$ By the Riesz Representation theorem (RRT), $C[0,1]^* = M.$

Let $f_n(x) = x^n.$ Suppose $f\in C[0,1]$ and $f_n\to f$ weakly in $C[0,1].$ By RRT, that is the same as saying $\int_{[0,1]}f_n \,d\mu \to \int_{[0,1]}f \,d\mu$ for all $\mu\in M.$

Now for $0\le x \le a< 1,$ $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,a].$ Hence $\int_{[0,a]}f_n\,d\mu \to 0$ for every $\mu \in M.$ Thus $\int_{[0,a]}f\,d\mu =0$ for all $\mu\in M.$ By the RRT (restricted to $[0,a]$) we have $f\chi_{[0,a]} = 0.$ It follows that $f = 0$ on $[0,1).$ Since $f\in C[0,1],$ $f=0$ on $[0,1].$ This leads to a contradiction by letting $\mu$ be the unit point mass at $1.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f\equiv0$. Then $f_n-f\xrightarrow{\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty}0$ on $[0,1)$. For for any $T\in\mathrm{dual}(\mathscr C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$, we have that $T(f_n-f)\to0$ on $[0,1)$, since $T$ is continuous.

Therefore since $\{f_n\}$ is bounded, and since $T(f_n)\to T(f)$ on $[0,1)$ which is dense in $[0,1]$, we have that $f_n$ is weakly convergent to $f$.

Comment: $||f_n-f||_{\infty}=1$ for all $n$, even if you restrict to $[0,1)$.